# How to extract URI argument result from deeplink navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

My goal is to extract the URI that was passed to my navController to navigate to destination B

so from A I do this

```
navController.navigate("myApp://destination")
```

From B I want to get this `"myApp://destination"` uri, this is because extra logic needs to be done after going to B from A, for this, I don't want to use any arguments in the navGraph

So after debugging I see that I can access mData from arguments and see the uri

[image]

Is there a way I can retrieve this URI from Fragment B ?

Problem from the above scenario is that I don't have the type or key to extract that uri from the arguments object without explicitly sending it myself

For external deeplinks opening the app it is working with `activity.intent.data` but for this in-app navigation I don't find a way to get this URI

A workaround could be sending it as parameter string from `navigate()` method and then get that from fragment B , but I want to know if there is a better way of doing it without involving writing an argument tag inside the navigation graph and add more code for it.

Comment: Can you explain what "this is because extra logic needs to be done after going to B from A, for this, I don't want to use any arguments in the navGraph" means?

Comment: I see that the duplicated answer is more for distinguish if I'm opening the uri from a deeplink or not, I'm trying to get the URI from the navigation itself inside the app, without sending it as an argument @ianhanniballake

Comment: Context is that I have a custom viewpager (switcher between 2 views) and I need to open one of these views with a deeplink that launches the app externally, but there is another way that I need to do that and is from within the app itself, and since I already have the uri, I don't want to pass an extra argument within the app to navigate to the same place as the deeplink is going from an external usage. So I saw that inside the arguments data navigating inside the app I can see the URI there, but I wonder how to get it since I did not passed it anywhere, the navcontroller launched that fragmen

Comment: As per the other question, the deep link URI is automatically provided as an argument by the NavController and you use `KEY_DEEP_LINK_INTENT` to get that deep link.